# Why can't graphs cross vertical asymptotes but cross horizontal asymptotes

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I am revising Calculus 1 on Khan Academy, and he stated and graphed that graphs cannot cross a vertical asymptote but they can cross and even oscillate around horizontal ones. Why is this? Isn't the point of an asymptote that the graph cannot touch the point and will approach infinity when approaching the value of the asymptote? Or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding? Would really like some clarifications. Thank you!

Here is the video: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-1/cs1-limits-and-continuity/cs1-infinite-limits/v/infinite-limits-and-asymptotes?modal=1

Comment: I assume you are talking about the graph of a function. For vertical asymptotes, remember that a function is single-valued - it gives only one y value for each x-value in its domain. For non-vertical asymptotes, all that matters is the behaviour as x goes to infinity (or negative infinity), where the graph gets closer to a line. That does not mean it can't cross the line, going above or below it, just that it doesn't get far away from it. Vertical asymptotes are really very different things than non-vertical ones.

Comment: The vertical asymptote appears in the point where the function is not defined. What does the value of $y$ have to be then?